# I need help on a VWO Split URL experiment

Tags: vwo

I need some help regarding split URL testing. The issue is that the URL I need to test includes a customer id. I am trying to see how I can exclude the customer id from the URL so we can run the experiment. Including the customer ID would only gather data for that specific customer. I require something that would capture all customers. Is there anything that can be done? I was told to use the asterisk (*) instead as a wildcard but that does not seem to work. As a reference, listed below is the URL.

https://companyname/quote/903282/auto/drivers/add

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL matches pattern option and mention a pattern so that it would include all the URLs with different customer IDs. Refer to the details below :

URL matches pattern : https://companyname/quote/*/auto/drivers/add

For more details, please refer to the below article :
https://help.vwo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021127714-Using-URL-Patterns-in-VWO

Also, is it an A/B test or a Split URL test? If it's a Split URL test, please make the pattern for the Variation URL as well.